# How to create a new file on remote computer on windows using win32 in c++?

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have one remote computer with **\\XYZ** Hostname and my code will execute on other computer. I want to create a new file and write some data inside that file on remote computer of Hostname **\\XYZ** using other computer. Both Windows machine are able to ping and no firewall is enable between these two computer. Please give me some code example to perform the same task.

I have tried to execute the code as i am pasting below but i was unable to the file on remote computer

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\?\\UNC\\XYZ\\C$\\test.txt",    // name of the file
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // open for writing
        0,             // sharing mode, none in this case
        0,             // use default security descriptor
        CREATE_ALWAYS, // overwrite if exists
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);
    if (h)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateFile() succeeded\n";
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateFile() failed:" << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But using the above code i am not able to create the file. 
Kindly provide me some code.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `GetLastError` return?  Note also that `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure, not `NULL`.  And you don't need (or want) `using namespace std`.

Comment: Please read the documentation for [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to see, why you are calling it at a time where it doesn't return a meaningful value. Also read the documentation for [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) to learn how it reports error. In all, there are 2 API calls and 2 API documentations ignored. This isn't going to be a route to success.

Comment: yes i have tried also ```h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE``` thats not going to else condition its showing message as ```CreateFile() succeeded``` but on remote computer i am not able to see the file.

Comment: you need first call `NetUseAdd`  to *"\\\\XYZ\\IPC$"* for set user name /password for remote system

Comment: I can not provide username and password, when i am trying to create the one File on remote computer

Comment: @YogendraKumar - without this you can not create or open file. probably `GetLastError()` return `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE` for you

Comment: @YogendraKumar To test for *success*, use `h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. To test for *failure*, use `h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Which operator you use to perform the comparison is important.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I have already tried the same ```h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE``` its not coming inside this condition and creating successfully message displaying, but when i login using "Windows + R" and gives ```\\Hostname\C$``` and login once using credential then executed the same program then file created sucessfully but if i restart the remote system and try again to create file without login procedure its not create the file on remote computer and did not get  ```h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE```, message shows create successfully.

Comment: @YogendraKumary Restart both your local machine and remote machine and try again to see the result.

Comment: @YogendraKumar Try to login remote machine via Remote Desktop Connection to see if you can create a file in target folder. For example, `D:\test`, if you can, then this code line will success: `CreateFile(L"//remote_machine_name/d/test/test.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);`